# Ejecutar en Docker una imagen amd64 en arm (Raspberry OS)

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, raspbian, arm

Hay una imagen de Docker de [Rotating TOR](https://github.com/mattes/rotating-proxy) que siempre en usado en arquitecturas amd64 sin problemas. Y estoy tratando de ejecutar esta imagen en una Raspberry Pi pero hasta el momento no lo he Logrado.

Al ejecutar la imagen recibo este error:

> $ docker run -d -p 5566:5566 -p 4444:4444 --env tors=25 mattes/rotating-proxy
>
> WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm/v7) and no specific platform was requested

Encontré algo de que hay que agregar el término `platform linux/adm64` después del `run` este hace que ya no bote el WARNING pero no funciona la imagen.

También he encontrado que se puede construir la imagen a `linux/arm/v7` con builx de Docker pero no he tenido éxito porque no se mucho de Docker. Agradezco a quien sepa un poco al respecto de como ejecutar esta imagen.

¡Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si la imagen soporta ser ejecutada en múltiples arquitecturas puedes intentar definir la plataforma específica:

```
docker run -d --platform linux/arm/v7 -p 5566:5566 -p 4444:4444 --env tors=25 mattes/rotating-proxy
```

El problema con ejecutar contenedores docker desde otras arquitecturas como Raspberry es que a veces la imagen no esta construida por default para ser ejecutada sobre la arquitectura del host.

De hecho, el error te está diciendo que por default docker intenta usar la plataforma *linux/amd64* pero la plataforma del host, o sea la raspberry, es *linux/arm/v7*.

Answer (score 0):

El tag `platform linux/adm64` funciona para especificar la plataforma que quieres utilizar si esta disponible, pero no es que haga que docker cambie la arquitectura donde se esta ejecutando `Docker`, esto quiere decir Docker en Raspberry Pi solo puede ejecutar imagines en disponibles en `ARM`, si bien las imágenes cada vez están siendo compiladas en múltiples arquitecturas, pero estarás mucho mas limitado que una arquitectura amd64, en el explorador de `Docker Hub` puedes filtrar imagines que tengan disponibles la arquitectura ARM, pero la de rotating-proxy no es ta disponibles.

La única opción que tendrías es que descargaras el proyecto y lo adaptaras para ARM, veo que el proyecto utiliza principalmente HAProxy y Ruby que si están disponible para arquitectura `ARM`.